# Evento jQuery sem interação do usuário

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, eventos

Estou acessando o banco de dados MySQL e dando um Select em uma tabela q vai retornar vários ddd's e telefones, com esses dados eu iriei enviar para um servidor via get ou post usando jquery com ajax. O problema é que não vai ter interação do usuário, vai rodar só no servidor. Atualmente, estou listando com PHP e enviando com um clique no botão. Como faria para o jQuery e o Ajax depois de listar os ddd's e telefones envie para outro servidor esses dados um atrás do outro?

Comment: Podes mostrar o código que tens e explicar que dados queres enviar sem interação?

Comment: Não poderia fazer tudo no load dá página?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui solucionar utilizando o focus() do jQuery. Eu defino que o campo vai ter o foco e crio um evento para quando ele estiver em foco, nesse evento eu envio os dados utilizando Ajax. A variável $n serve para diferenciar os id's, por isso que quando ele vai procurar os id's eu coloquei para o PHP  dar um echo no $n, tendo assim, cada item que for achado no banco um índice definido por $n e cada id numerado. No final, o foco muda para o outro input porquê esse não tem evento nenhum associado, fiz isso pois, nos testes ele estava repetindo infinitas vezes o envio do último e com esse "jeito" resolveu. Não preciso de interação do usuário.

```
<?php
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "login", "senha", "banco") or die (mysql_error ());
        $sql = "SELECT `ddd_deps`, `tel_deps`, `nome_deps` FROM `deps` WHERE `sit_deps` = 1 AND `usu_login_usu` = '".$_GET['usu']."'; ";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        $n=1;

        //lista os dados em inputs para puxá-los pelo id
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "<input type='text' name='ddd".$n."' id='ddd".$n."' required='required' value='".$row["ddd_deps"]."'>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='tel".$n."' id='tel".$n."' required='required' value='".$row["tel_deps"]."'>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='nome".$n."' id='nome".$n."' required='required' value='".$row["nome_deps"]."'><br>";
            ?>

            <!--script para enviar para servidor via get-->
            <script>
                $(function(){
                    $("#nome<?php echo $n; ?>").focus();
                });
                $( "#nome<?php echo $n; ?>" ).focus(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type      : 'get',
                        url       : 'http://'+ $('#ip').val()+':8443/server',
                        data      : 'ddd='+ $('#ddd<?php echo $n; ?>').val() +'&tel='+ $('#tel<?php echo $n; ?>').val() +'&nome='+ $('#nome<?php echo $n; ?>').val(),
                        dataType  : 'html',
                        success : function(txt){
                            $("#ddd<?php echo $n; ?>").focus();
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>

            <?php
            $n++;
        }
?>
```